# Python mouseclick not working inside subroutine

Tags: python, excel, winapi, mouse, sendkeys

Question: Why would a win32api mouse click work in the main block but fail in a subroutine?

I'm working on a python script that copies an id from an Excel spreadsheet and pastes it into a 3rd party app. The code works when everything is running in the main python body.

However, copying the leftclick call that selects the Excel spreadsheet to a subroutine  and then invoking the subroutine to call leftclick silently fails.  When selExcel exits, the subsequent sendkey issues the intended copy command. But because the selExcel leftclick silently failed, the ctrl-c is passed to the powershell window that invoked the python script instead of Excel. Python responds to the ctrl-c by killing the script and issuing a keyboard interrupt message.

So again, why can't I call leftclick from a subroutine but I can from the main body?

I'm running python 3.10.4 in Windows 10.
For the curious, I'm was trying to abstract the window positions by using subroutines in lieu of leaving the leftclick calls inline. Now I'm just mystified why stuffing the leftclick call into the subroutine fails

Here's the code

```
import win32api, win32con,win32com.client
import time as t
import os
import sys

def leftclick(x,y):
    win32api.SetCursorPos((x,y))
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,x,y,0,0)
    t.sleep(.1)
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,x,y,0,0)
 
def sp(x,y):
  win32api.SetCursorPos((x,y))

def selExcel():
  leftclick(1550,20) # click excel Window
  t.sleep(.1)

def selConfig():
   leftclick (100,100) # select 3rd party app 
   t.sleep(.1)

#leftclick(1550,20) # click excel Window  -- this line works if uncommented instead of calling selExcel
#t.sleep(.1) 
selExcel

t.sleep(.1)
w = win32com.client.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")   
w.SendKeys("^c")  # copy id -- this line fails if I call selExcel 

....code continues
```

Comment: Excel has an [automation interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/troubleshoot/office-developer/automate-excel-from-visual-basic). Is there a specific reason you're avoiding it?

Comment: @IInspectable Because I'm driving a 3rd party app that doesn't have an automation interface. Mouseclicks and sendkeys is what the other app understands.

Comment: That neither explains why you fiddle with fake input to activate an Excel window, nor why you aren't using [UI Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/entry-uiauto-win32) to interact with the application that doesn't have a dedicated automation interface. As for the concrete failure mode: Python is just a garbage programming language with ad-hoc scoping rules. The issue can literally be anywhere.

Comment: @IInspectable Skimming the UI documentation it appears there's a steep learning curve to pick it up.    Would you mind banging out the C equivalent of the Python above using UI automation as an example of what's involved?

Comment: If you're aiming for the equivalent then that means you're avoiding UI Automation. UIA operates at a higher level; there's no simulating input involved. You would rather traverse the accessible tree, and invoke actions on items. You can use the [Inspect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/inspect-objects) tool to get a rough idea of what's required (and available). Don't get confused by the *"We recommend using Accessibility Insights instead."* comment. It's **far** behind what the *"legacy tool"* Inspect provides.

Comment: Not sure what you're saying here. My goal is to get a 3rd party app which exposes nothing more than text fields and buttons to accept data as if a person had entered it.  If your approach entails fetching a reference to the topmost window, inspecting the window for subwindows until I find the reference to the text input field, sending a message to the text field that contains the desired text, inspecting the window for a reference to the button and sending a message to the button that it's been clicked, that's quite a bit more code than using Python to simulate keystrokes and mouse clicks.

Comment: If your requirement is to deliver a robust implementation, that allows a client to keep using their PC while it is executing, then that certainly has a shortest possible implementation. That could well be longer than the shortest program that doesn't have the requirement of being robust. Not sure how comparing metrics of unrelated pieces of software would somehow expose useful data.